# How to find minima and maxima of a function. I am limited to using numpy, sympy and matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I am asked to find the maxima and minima of few functions. One of the functions is y = (9x^3) - (7x^2) + (3x) + 10
The code I could write so far is:

```
from sympy import*
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = symbols ('x')
f = (9*x**3) - (7*x**2) + (3*x) + 10

intervals = np.arange(-5, 7)

df = diff(f, x)
df2 = diff(f, x, 2)

f = lambdify (x, f)
y = f(intervals)

print (intervals)
print (y)
```

I am new to using these 3 libraries so I dont know how to find the answer using these 3 libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SymPy can tell you the derivative and `f` and can tell you when a function is zero. Since max/min occur when the derivative is zero you can find the zeros and then determine if those values make the 2nd derivative positive or negative, e.g.

```
>>> from sympy import real_roots
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> f = -x**2 + 1
>>> d1 = f.diff(x)
>>> d2 = d1.diff(x)  # = f.diff(x,2)
>>> extrema = real_roots(d1)
>>> for i in extrema:
...   if d2.subs(x, i).is_positive:
...      print('minimum',i)
...   else:
...      print('maxima',i)
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47420887/1089161). (If there are no real roots then there are no extrema for real values of `x`.)

Comment: how do I solve this equation if I am given a boundary of x coordinates?
Just saw that one of the questions asked me to find maxima and minima of f(x) in the interval [-5, 5]

Comment: `solveset` can be used to specify the range in which you wish to find a solution, `solveset(d1, x, Interval(-5,5))`.

Comment: in which line should I add `solveset`?

Comment: `extrema = solveset(d1,x,Interval(-5,5))` should work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the values of `intervals` into the formula and then get the minimum value, you can specify the `intervals` firstly and then just put this array into the formula instead `x`:

```
intervals = np.random.permutation(10)
# [8 4 3 0 2 7 9 1 6 5]

f = (9 * intervals ** 3) - (7 * intervals ** 2) + (3 * intervals) + 10
# [4194  486  199   10   60 2775 6031   15 1720  975]

f.argmin()    # --> will get index of the minimum value
# 3

f.min()       # --> will get minimum value resulted by the formula
# 10
```

or if you want to use the formula many times, you can define it as a function and just call it every time you need instead writing it again as:

```
def formula_1(x):
    return (9 * x ** 3) - (7 * x ** 2) + (3 * x) + 10


results = formula_1(intervals)
results.min()
```